# Java Regex a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and (.)(_)(-)

Tags: java, regex

Writing a simple regex, but I've never been very good at this.

What I'm trying to do is check a string (filename) to make sure it only contains a-z, A-Z, 0-9 or the special characters underscore (_) period (.) or dash (-).

Here's what I have

```
if(filename.length() < 1 || !filename.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9[.][_][-]]+"))
   return false;
else
   return true;
```

This appears to work, but does not look very elegant to me.  Is there a better / more readable way to write this?

Thanks in advance!  Just trying to learn how to write these buggers better.

-Will

Comment: Others have answered the regex question well, but I'm curious why you check the length of the string is greater than 1. If the string is "", it cannot match `"^.+"`

Comment: Good point.  It was left over from a previous implementation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't need to use `[]` inside character class.

So, you can write:

```
^[-a-zA-Z0-9._]+
```

Also, you can use `\\w` instead of `a-zA-Z0-9_`.

So, the regexp would be:

```
^[-\\w.]+
```

Also, this regexp will match a string like `StackOverflow 22.10$$2011` by consuming `StackOverflow 22.10`. If you need your string to consist completely of those character, you should end the pattern with `$` - the end of the string:

```
^[-\\w.]+$
```

Comment: In fact, in most regex flavors those extra square brackets would be treated as a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks!  This looks much better

Comment: Using \\w will allow any UTF-8 character, not just a-z and A-Z. Also be aware that . matches any character and needs to be escaped if you mean a literal '.'

Comment: @MarkRotteveel `.` inside character class means literal `.`, and it doesn't need to be escaped as outside character class.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel As regards `\\w`. I'm used to Python flavor of regex engine. In Python `\\w` means the human-like string `\w` (we just escape `\ ` with another `\ `, otherwise `\w` would mean only one special symbol. We usually use `r` before the string to denote `raw` string, so that no escapes are needed `r'raw sring \w*'`.

Comment: @ovgolovin I am not talking about the escape, I am talking about the fact that \w is a lot broader than just a-z and A-Z as it includes all UTF-8 characters which can be used in words.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I got it. I will only add that in Python regex flavor matching Unicode characters switches on only when the [re.UNICODE](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html#compilation-flags) flag is used.

Comment: @ovgolovin You're correct, a similar behaviour is true in Java, `\w` only matches non-ASCII characters when UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS is set

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    boolean foundMatch = subjectString.matches("^[\\w.-]+$");
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Try this.

Basically \w is a shorthand for [a-zA-Z_0-9] and I simply add the other two characters you want.

Comment: I don't know Java's RE engine, but generally you need to anchor to the start of the string, or else "@#$%@#$%foo" will be accepted.

Comment: @OscarKorz Had already added the anchors before I saw the comment m8 :)

Comment: Java's `matches()` method automatically anchors the match at both ends, but it does no harm to use explicit anchors, and I think it's good policy to do so.  I don't see the point of that lookahead, though (i.e., `(?=[\\w.-]+$)`).  Also, be aware that PatternSyntaxException is a RuntimeException; you're not required to catch it.

Comment: @AlanMoore Lookahed as it is written just checks if the length is at least one, which is something that the OP also check. Just wanted to show that this is also possible with regex.

Comment: But your regex (`^[\\w.-]+$`) already requires at least one character.  The lookahead is totally redundant.

Comment: @AlanMoore Yeah you are right. The idea (when I wrote that) was that you could put a specific limit in there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that is more expensive (because it actually touches disk) but will be cross platform.

Essentially it creates a file with the given name, and deletes it if it didn't previously exist. If you attempted to create a file with an invalid name, it throws an error. So no matter what system you're on, it will tell you if the file name was proper.

Now it violates a general rule (using exceptions to determine program flow), and does have the disadvantage of going to disk. But it's a different approach and might give you ideas you can use.

```
public boolean isValidFileName(final String fileName) {
    final File file = new File(fileName);
    final boolean isValid = true;
    try {
        if (file.createNewFile()) {
            file.delete();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        isValid = false;
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: This will potentially return different results on different platforms.  That's the opposite of what's usually meant by cross-platform as I understand it.

Comment: The idea is that it provides an interface to functionality common to, but implemented differently on, different platforms. It's because each one does it different that this works so well. The only real issue is when you have one platform telling another platform what's okay or what isn't. And like I said this just a thought to give an avenue for other ideas.